# OpenCV / Python Bundle adjustment

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have an application where I am attempting structure from motion for multiple views from the same camera using OpenCV in Python. (OpenCV isn't a hard requirement but Python is right now).  Example: I have 16 camera images to work with with small motions between each frame.  In the frames (200x200) I can track ~50 features and I'd like to estimate camera pose and 3D point locations for the features as accurately as possible.

I'm at the point where I'd like to use a stream of frames (from video) to refine the estimates of camera pose and 3D point positions since estimating pose and triangulating 3D points from two frames produces a lot of noise.  I believe Bundle Adjustment is the next obvious direction to go in, but I'm not finding any obvious Python implementation of bundle adjustment to use.  Many options (such as LevMarqSparse::bundleAdjust()) appear to be only partially completed or not fully adopted.

What is a good place to start?  I guess I'm looking for a relatively simple Python bundle adjustment to prototype with and see if that is a direction I want to invest more time into.

Comment: You may take a look at [stitching_detailed.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stitching_detailed.py) code sample. There are few `BundleAdjuster` classes, like [BundleAdjusterRay](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d7c/classcv_1_1detail_1_1BundleAdjusterRay.html). It's probably **not** what you are looking for...

Comment: It's a too broad question. Please clarify the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a calibrated camera and an initial estimate of intrinsics and extrinsic parameters, you could at first perform a simple bundle adjustment directly in Python.
For instance, you could use stacks of three images, compute 3D points from the feature points via the homogeneous triangulation method. A simple bundle adjustment as a first prototype can be build for instance via scipy.least_squares and the Trusted Region Reflective non-linear optimization technique. Check out this [tutorial](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/bundle_adjustment.html).

Afterwards you can decide, whether you want to implement or use a Levenberg-Marquardt optimization technique which is able to handle sparse Jacobians or even determine the Jacobian analytically to hypothetically increase the convergence if desired.

So far, I think there is no adequate library in Python which provides a potent and high performant implementation of bundle adjustment.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!  This is what I was looking for!